# How to match a specific character following a number in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How, in a regular expression, do I specify that I only want to match a string in which a number is followed by a specific character (or another number), but anything else following a number should not match?  That is, if my special character is a ":", this should match:

```
"1:9"
```

but this should not:

```
"1:9-2"
```

Because in the string above, there is an instance of a "-" that follows the number "9".  I thought I had the right regexp, but this is returning true for the above two cases:

```
2.4.0 :001 > ab = "1:3"
 => "1:3"
2.4.0 :002 > ab =~ /\d:\d/
 => 0
2.4.0 :003 > ab = "1:3-4"
 => "1:3-4"
2.4.0 :004 > ab =~ /\d:\d/
 => 0
```

Comment: Do you expect end of string after the second `\d` (`/\d:\d\z/`)? Or match the entire string like `/\A\d:\d\z/`?

Comment: Please proof-read your questions before posting and remove any irb-prompts.

Comment: `but anything else following a number should not match` If you're trying to exclude strings with anything _other_ than what is matched in a regex, it has to have anchors `^` <your regex> `$`. Otherwise, you have to define your problem better.

Comment: Hey @Wiktor, It doesn't have to be the end of the string after the second number.  I would expect this pattern to match as well, "1:23:4556" since every instance of a number is followed by either anoterh number or the ":".

Comment: Does it mean you want to match a string that only consists of series of colon-separated digits? Like `/\A\d+(?::\d+)*\z/`? Or do you want to negate the `-` + `digit` after the `\d:\d` pattern like `/\d:\d(?!-\d)/`? Sorry, your question is very unclear.

Comment: It would be the first one, /\A\d+(?::\d+)*\z/, with the exception of the fact that the string can contain other characters, so "CR2:45" is legal by my (vague) definition, its just that if anything follows a number, it better be another number or the ":" (end of line is acceptable as well).

Comment: Just an idea - what about `/\A(?!.*\d[^\d:])/m`? Or just `/\d[^\d:]/` to test if there is a digit followed with any char but digit or `:` (if no match, it is OK, else, not OK)?

Comment: That last one is looking pretty good.  It seems to match things that are all letters (e.g. "NA"), but I think I can easily get around that by just checking if the string contains numbers and then applying teh regexp.

Comment: Could you please explain the requirements in plain English? I do not know how to answer your question. Btw, I removed the previous comment with `/\A[[:alnum:]]+(?::[[:alnum:]]+)*\z/`, I guess you meant that one in the above comment. To make sure there is at least 1 digit, you may use a lookahead: `/\A(?=\D*\d)[[:alnum:]]+(?::[[:alnum:]]+)*\z/`. Please check [this regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/dxHglkGMSm) and let know if I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Please check http://rubular.com/r/dxHglkGMSm and let know if I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138680/discussion-between-wiktor-stribizew-and-dave).

Comment: Hey that rubular link you posted is a winner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you need to match a string that presents a colon-separated alphanumeric strings that must contain at leat one digit.

You need to use

```
/\A(?=\D*\d)[[:alnum:]]+(?::[[:alnum:]]+)*\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/dxHglkGMSm) (adapted for a multiline test string)

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of  a string anchor
- `(?=\D*\d)` - a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) requiring a digit (`\d`) after 0+ chars other than a digit (`\D*`)
- `[[:alnum:]]+` - 1 or more letters or digits
- `(?::[[:alnum:]]+)*` -  zero or more sequences of:

  - `:` - a colon
  - `[[:alnum:]]+` - 1 or more letters/digits
- `\z` - end of string.